# CoreBluetooth / RxBluetoothKit: How to forget a device?

Tags: core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, rxiosble

Is there a way to make the bluetooth central "forget" a device, so it's not paired anymore?

I know that [only some devices Require a Paired Connection to Access Sensitive Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH5-SW9). Let's say I am referring to those. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254932/can-you-pair-a-bluetooth-le-device-in-an-ios-app)

I am looking for something that allows the user to tap on a "forget" button, to later re-pair the device and connect/disconnect to it. (Without having to go to settings app )

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
The user has to manually go to the Bluetooth settings and forget the device.

All apps which use BLE and present on the app store ask the user to manually go to Settings and forget the pairing.