# How to connect Bluetooth device to application without pairing in iOS? My BLE device transmits data when connected without pairing

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

How to connect Bluetooth device to application without pairing in iOS?
My BLE device transmits data when connected without pairing.

I am following normal connection of device after discovery.

```
centralManager?.connect(device, options: nil)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.
[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]
[image: pic5]

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Pairing (Bonding) is only needed if your characteristics are encrypted.  If your characteristics are encrypted then there is no way to avoid bonding.

Comment: @Paulw11
As soon as I connect the device, I get the "Bluetooth pairing request" alert even before discovering services and characteristics.
And as per the 'Bluetooth Communication Specifications' of the device I have it transmits data when connected with Unpair.
If I cancel the pairing request It works fine. I also receives data. But if I go with pairing, application don't get notification for the data sent from device to application.

Comment: What kind of device are you trying to connect to? iOS should handle pairing itself and only pair if you are trying to access a characteristic that needs encryption. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254932/can-you-pair-a-bluetooth-le-device-in-an-ios-app) for more info.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan
(lldb) po print(characteristic)
<CBCharacteristic: 0x280ea8960, UUID = 7EAFD361-F151-4785-B307-47D34ED52C3C, properties = 0x10, value = {length = 7, bytes = 0x100a02db060000}, notifying = NO>
(lldb) po print(characteristic.properties.contains(.notifyEncryptionRequired))
false
(lldb) po print(characteristic.properties.contains(.notify))
true
(lldb) po print(characteristic.properties.contains(.authenticatedSignedWrites))
false
(lldb) po print(characteristic.properties.contains(.indicateEncryptionRequired))
false

Comment: What kind of deice are you trying to connect to? Please try connecting using a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) and see if pairing happens as well

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan
yes, there also pairing pop up appears. Does that conclude anything?

Comment: You can see that the characteristic has `notifyEncryptionRequired` so you will get a pairing prompt. The only way to avoid it would be to change the firmware on your peripheral to not require encryption

Comment: @Paulw11
Pasted the screenshot from nRF Connect. I don't see 'notifyEncryptionRequired'. Please have a look.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan
Pasted the screenshot from nRF Connect. I don't see 'notifyEncryptionRequired'. Please have a look.